# Word macro that adds the file name to the body text of a series of Word documents in a folder

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need a Word macro that adds the file name of a document to the first line of that Word document.  But not just one document at a time.  I would like the Macro to add these file names to a series of Word documents in a particular folder (with each document getting their own file name).

A Macro that adds the file name to document is simple:

```
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    Text:= "FILENAME  "
Selection.TypeParagraph
```

But how can I get it to add file names to an entire series of documents in a folder?   I suppose the folder could be named in the Macro.  For example: `C:\Users\username\Desktop\somefolder\`.  I also suppose that a Loop could be used to go through the folder until the loop gets to the end of the documents in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should at least get you started. I haven't tested it, but I've written this type of thing a few times before, so the basic idea works.

```
Dim filePath As String
Dim thisDoc As Document
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Set wordApp = New Word.Application

'wordApp.Visible = True ' uncomment if you want to watch things happen

'Get first file that matches
filePath = Dir("C:\Users\username\Desktop\somefolder\*.doc") ' or *.whatever
Do While filePath <> ""
    Set thisDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(filePath)

    'Add filename at top of document
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.InsertAfter filePath
    'Selection.InsertAfter ThisDocument.FullName ' alternative
    'Your way using .Fields.Add is also fine if you want the file name as 
    ' a field instead of 
    ' plain text.

    thisDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Get next file that matches and start over
    filePath = Dir()
Loop

wordApp.Quit
Set wordApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!  I'll play with this to see if I can get it to work.  Thanks again!